# How to create advanced queries for azure table storage in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-table-storage

I am working with Azure table storage in NodeJS using the azure-storage package (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node)

According to the documentation an advanced query can be created and executed like this

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var tableService = azure.createTableService();
var query = new azure.TableQuery()
  .top(5)
  .where('PartitionKey eq ?', 'part2');

tableSvc.queryEntities('mytable', query, null, function(error, result, response) {
  if (!error) {
    // result.entries contains entities matching the query
  }
});
```

This code works. However all of the query operators documented are very basic ones (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894031.aspx). Does any know any of the other operators or another way to write queries against the Azure table storage within NodeJS? (for instance something similar to inner queries?)

Comment: When it comes to querying Azure Tables, options are somewhat limited. Is there any particular scenario you have in mind? Please share that so that someone can help you with that.

Comment: I was looking for things similar to inner queries in sql with other tables or maybe joins? Since to the best of my knowledge azure-tables don't support storing object/arrays as a value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that aggregation query operations are still not supported for Azure Table Storage in service tier but the client SDK tier, you can find the all supported and not supported operations at [Query Operators Supported for the Table Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135725.aspx)

As if you need to use relational queries, you can refer to traditional database services, like MySQL or SQL Server.